# how can I hide an element when using slice in jquery?

Tags: jquery

Here is my current code:

```js
$('.list-request-negotiating-loadmore').on('click', function(){
  $(".request-negotiating-item:hidden").slice(0, 3).show();
  if($(".request-negotiating-item:hidden").length < 3){
      $('.list-request-negotiating-loadmore').hide();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="dashboard-info list-requests request-negotiating" >
<div class="enquiry request-item request-negotiating-item" >1</div>
<div class="enquiry request-item request-negotiating-item" >2</div>
<div class="enquiry request-item request-negotiating-item" style="display: none;">3</div>
<div class="enquiry request-item request-negotiating-item" style="display: none;">4</div>
<div class="enquiry request-item request-negotiating-item" style="display: none;">5</div>
<div class="enquiry request-item request-negotiating-item" style="display: none;">6</div>
<div class="enquiry request-item request-negotiating-item" style="display: none;">7</div>
</div>
<div class="dashboard-title list-request-negotiating-loadmore loadmore" style="">load more</div>
```

If there are less than 3 hidden divs, I'd like it to hide the `loadmore` button, but for some reason my code isn't working properly.

Comment: Your code is working just fine. Do you see any errors in console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code seems to work but from a user experience wouldn't you want something closer to this

```js
$('.list-request-negotiating-loadmore').on('click', function(){
  $(".request-negotiating-item:hidden").slice(0, 3).show();
  if($(".request-negotiating-item:hidden").length < 1){
      $('.list-request-negotiating-loadmore').hide();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="dashboard-info list-requests request-negotiating" >
<div class="enquiry request-item request-negotiating-item" >1</div>
<div class="enquiry request-item request-negotiating-item" >2</div>
<div class="enquiry request-item request-negotiating-item" style="display: none;">3</div>
<div class="enquiry request-item request-negotiating-item" style="display: none;">4</div>
<div class="enquiry request-item request-negotiating-item" style="display: none;">5</div>
<div class="enquiry request-item request-negotiating-item" style="display: none;">6</div>
<div class="enquiry request-item request-negotiating-item" style="display: none;">7</div>
<div class="enquiry request-item request-negotiating-item" style="display: none;">8</div>
<div class="enquiry request-item request-negotiating-item" style="display: none;">9</div>
<div class="enquiry request-item request-negotiating-item" style="display: none;">10</div>
<div class="enquiry request-item request-negotiating-item" style="display: none;">11</div>
<div class="enquiry request-item request-negotiating-item" style="display: none;">12</div>
</div>
<div class="dashboard-title list-request-negotiating-loadmore loadmore" style="">load more</div>
```